# Apply CSS rules to OpenLayers vector feature

Tags: openlayers

I'd like to simplify my code by using the same css styles on my SVG piechart and on my OpenLayers vector layer. This way if I ever change the css to have a different colour for one feature type I only have one place to modify.
However, I can't find a way of setting the css class of a feature on a vector layer. Is is possible? I'd probably have to use a style map and context though I could set the class as I create each feature.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do like this in your css file:

```
svg[id *= "_something"]
{
    stylexyz1: valuexyz1;
    stylexyz2: valuexyz2;
    stylexyz3: valuexyz3;
    stylexyz4: valuexyz4;
    stylexyz5: valuexyz5;
}
```